# Javascript : How to get unique Id for multiple duplicate records

Tags: javascript, object, duplicates, distinct-values

say we have a object:

```
   var db = [
        {Id: "201" , Player: "Jon",price: "3.99", loc: "NJ" },
        {Id: "202", Player: "Sam",price: "4.22", loc: "PA" },
        {Id: "203" ,Player: "Sam",price: "4.22", loc: "NY" },
        {Id: "204", Player: "Bill",price: "3.22", loc: "TX" },
        {Id: "205" ,Player: "Dave",price: "3.99", loc: "WA" },
        {Id: "206" ,Player: "Dave",price: "3.99", loc: "WI" },
];
```

202,203,205,206 have similar values for player and price but I need just one id for similar values i.e, output should be 202,205.

Comment: Do you want records that match price && player or match price or player etc..

Comment: i need one unique Id for records that match both player and price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` first to return object with count of each `Player|price` combination. Then you can use another reduce, and check if count of `Player|price` number if `> 1`. If it is then add objects id to array.

```js
var db = [
   {Id: "201" ,Player: "Jon",price: "3.99", loc: "NJ" },
   {Id: "202", Player: "Sam",price: "4.22", loc: "PA" },
   {Id: "203" ,Player: "Sam",price: "4.22", loc: "NY" },
   {Id: "204", Player: "Bill",price: "3.22", loc: "TX" },
   {Id: "205" ,Player: "Dave",price: "3.99", loc: "WA" },
   {Id: "206" ,Player: "Dave",price: "3.99", loc: "WI" },
];

var obj = db.reduce(function(o, e) {
  o[e.Player + '|' + e.price] = (o[e.Player + '|' + e.price] || 0) + 1;
    return o;
}, {});

var result = db.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(obj[e.Player + '|' + e.price] > 1) r.push(e.Id);
    return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Is their any way, i can borrow down to one record each for duplicate values?
Like 202 and 203 has same values so need to display only one of them

Comment: Which one you want to use?

Comment: In above example as 202&203 and 205&206 have similar properties, i need only one of each.

Output: 202 and 205

Comment: That is another question so this answer and other answers are for your original question but you could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1027/

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = []; 

db.forEach(function(item, index){  
   db.forEach(function(item2, index2){ 
      if (index == index2) return;
      if (item.Player == item2.Player && item.price == item2.price) {   
         if(result.indexOf(item.Id) < 0){  
           result.push(item.Id);
         }
         if(result.indexOf(item2.Id) < 0){
           result.push(item2.Id);
         }
      }
   });
});

console.log(result); // [202,203,205,206]
```

I am not saying that it is the most correct decision ever, but it is working and understandable enough. You may check it yourself via this snippet with comments:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKWZKx

Comment: I edited the question a little, as in the example 202 -203 and 205-206 has similar values, can I get only one of each i.e, 203 and 205 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID with simple loop.

```js
var db = [
        {Id: "201" , Player: "Jon",price: "3.99", loc: "NJ" },
        {Id: "202", Player: "Sam",price: "4.22", loc: "PA" },
        {Id: "203" ,Player: "Sam",price: "4.22", loc: "NY" },
        {Id: "204", Player: "Bill",price: "3.22", loc: "TX" },
        {Id: "205" ,Player: "Dave",price: "3.99", loc: "WA" },
        {Id: "206" ,Player: "Dave",price: "3.99", loc: "WI" },
];

for(var i = 0; i < db.length; i++){
  var obj = db[i];
  console.log('Id: ', obj.Id);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but did you read the question? Topicstarter asks for  finding special duplicates and then return their IDs as a result.